# start working with cloud computing

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting

I am very new to cloud computing. I was wondering can i develop a website using LAMP stack on cloud.
And which cloud to use. Is there any open source cloud out there to use it.

Comment: cloud buzzword + lamp stack sounds like a server fault thing

Comment: @lunixbochs - its not dude. it will come here only i believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. You can use [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/downloads) to develop applications that would run on Amazon's EC2 using the LAMP stack. Eucalyptus is open source. Everything you run on an EC2 instance can be open source, but the actual EC2 instance is paid for (if that's what you were trying to avoid).

EC2 is cloud computing in the Hardware-as-a-service sense.

You can use Java or Python (and soon Go) to develop applications on Google AppEngine, but you don't even see the operating system and the application container is not really applicable. So that kills the LA portion of LAMP. Also, AppEngine uses various DataStore API hooks, so the M isn't really applicable. So as long as the P was Python and not PHP, you're golden (again, assuming P is a reasonable substitute for LAMP). On the plus side, you can do quite a bit before hitting the AppEngine quotas and having to pay for anything. Note that you can get an open source AppEngine work-alike with [appscale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/). As a bonus, appscale runs on Eucalyptus (this might have something to do with the fact that the creators of appscale and eucalyptus are married).

Heroku is good for deploying Rails applications, but that's not exactly LAMP, either.

Heroku and AppEngine are cloud computing in the Platform-as-a-service sense.

(hopefully you get other answers)

Comment: I would suggest AppEngine. I use it for my PhD research primarily because I can run quite a bit on it before having to pay anything.

Answer (score 2):

The term "cloud computing" is kind of vague. If you're interested in distributed computing and parallel processing, you might want to look into [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of cloud-computing development opportunities/projects out there.  Everything from the Dropbox API to VMware vCloud Director APIs would be interesting to take a look at.

Try to get past the whole "Cloud" terminology overused by marketing and see what is actually being done with private and public cloud services.  You will find a wide range of platforms, APIs, and problems to be solved.

+1 for checking out Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I find it more satisfying to learn things by doing. So I took the same approach for cloud computing. For someone who just wants to get started with with [cloud computing with a real world example - check this code](http://aameer.github.io/cloud-computing-101/). Hopefully it would help someone in understanding cloud computing. You can find lots of theory online but same is not true with a practical real life code examples.