# Python resources for cloud computing learning?

Tags: python, scala, cloud

Is there a book or resource for learning cloud in Python or Scala? I know Django and app-engine but I am not that interested in learning more about a client framework. I'm interested in learning the core thing.

Comment: Could you please explain in greater detail what exactly do you want to learn? Do you want to learn how to manipulate cloud infrastructure with Python? If so it would depend on the provider (for example in case of Amazon AWS you might look at http://code.google.com/p/boto/ )

Comment: What could "learning cloud" possibly mean?

Comment: something which might get you started quickly http://stackoverflow.com/a/36349458/2833695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve Marx published a blog post describing a [python sample](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/tutorial-running-a-python-web-application-in-windows-azure) running in Windows Azure, with the Rocket web server. The code is on [github](https://github.com/smarx/pythonrole).

This will show you some interesting elements of setting up a python app in Windows Azure, including startup tasks. You'll still want to take a look at the Windows Azure [Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396) to get a deeper understanding of Windows Azure.

Comment: thanks, sadly i'm one point away from being able to vote up. but i'll do it when i reach them