# Running scripts on cloud

Tags: python, azure, cloud

I'm new to cloud computing domain. Here is what I've:
1) A domain.
2) A hosting space (on HostGator).
3) A Microsoft Azure account.

And here is what I need to do:
1) Take an input file from the user using HTML.
2) Processing the input file using a Python script.
3) Returning an output file generated by the script to the user.

How do I do this? Any rough steps?
I want to implement this using Microsoft Azure.
Though HostGator supposedly supports Python 2.7, I couldn't run my scripts there and got an Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: an internal error means you have an error in your code ... you should check the error logs ...

Comment: check this out (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36349458/2833695) it should help.

Answer (score 0):

As Azure is a cloud platform which provides a growing collection of integrated services.You can leverage [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/) to approach your need.

You can build your python project on local first, then create a Web app on [Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), and deploy your project to Azure Web app with Git, FTP or Visual Studio.

Here is an [official reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/) about how to deploy python project on Azure Web app step by step.

Also, you can configure a custom domain name in Azure Web Apps, for more information you can find in [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)